# Click a button in a web using R

Tags: r, rselenium

I want to autofill a form in a webpage. I am using RSelenium, and I get to complete all the form, but the "preferred language" field.

The webpage is: https://ontrack.sgs.com/es-ES/registration-form/

I also cannot solve the captcha, but the best wqay for that I figure that will be using an API.

I have tried to locate de button to click and get the pop up appear to select, but I haven't been able to do that.

I have tried this combinations and many more, but nothing seems to work:

```
library(RSelenium)

#browser parameters

rD <- rsDriver(port=4571L, browser = "chrome", chromever = "75.0.3770.90") # runs a chrome browser, wait for necessary files to download
remDrv <- rD$client
remDrv$open(silent = TRUE)
url<-paste("https://ontrack.sgs.com/es-ES/registration-form/",sep="")

#### Updating form

webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'class', "button")
webElem <- remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath", "//input[@class='button']")
# webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', ".launchentitylookup")
# webElem$clickElement()

webElem <- remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath", "//input[@name = 'ctl00$ctl00$ContentContainer$MainContent$EntityControls$EntityFormControl$EntityFormControl_EntityFormView$sgs_portallanguage_name' ]") 
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list("Español"))
webElem <- remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath", "//input[@name = 'ctl00$ctl00$ContentContainer$MainContent$EntityControls$EntityFormControl$EntityFormControl_EntityFormView$sgs_portallanguage' ]") 
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list("Español"))
webElem <- remDrv$findElement(using = "xpath", "//input[@name = 'ctl00$ctl00$ContentContainer$MainContent$EntityControls$EntityFormControl$EntityFormControl_EntityFormView$sgs_portallanguage_entityname' ]") 
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list("Español"))
```

I expect to be able to select a language in the form, Spanish in fact.

Apart from that, being able to solve or skip the captcha.

Comment: I am also interested if anybody posts a solution to bypass captcha. P.S. I am not a robot.

Comment: Breaking a captcha is a blatant violation of the intent of the site and you aren't likely to find help doing that on this forum. Fortunately, the site you mentioned does not have anything in their robots.txt preventing bots from scraping. However, now you are talking about autofilling a form which can be used for nefarious purposes and will make it less likely for people to aid you.

Comment: You mentioned an API. Why not use an API if one exists?

Comment: I just need it to fill the form for 4000 clients I have, and I wanted to automate it. Anyway, what I want to solve is the first part, how to choose a language from the pop up window.

Answer (score 1):

I must be very late but here is an answer to the query. Note that I am not including the captcha bit here because that isn't a part of the main question.

```
    library(RSelenium)

#browser parameters

rD <- rsDriver(port=4571L, browser = "chrome", chromever = "87.0.4280.20") # runs a chrome browser, wait for necessary files to download
remDrv <- rD$client
remDrv$open(silent = TRUE)
url<-paste("https://ontrack.sgs.com/es-ES/registration-form/",sep="")

remDrv$navigate(url)
#### Updating form

##open language search
remDrv$findElement(using = "css", "#sgs_portallanguage_entityname+ .input-group-btn .launchentitylookup")$clickElement()
Sys.sleep(3) ## wait for languages to load

#select lanaguage - should match the ones in the table
language<-'Español'

###language path
lang_path<-paste0("//*[contains(concat( ' ', @class, ' ' ), concat( ' ' , 'table-hover', ' ' ))]//*[contains(concat( ' ', @data-value, ' ' ), concat( ' ' , '",language,"', ' ' ))]")  


##selec language - Spanish
remDrv$findElement(using="xpath",lang)$clickElement()


##Press Select button
select_path<-"//*[(@id = 'sgs_portallanguage_lookupmodal')]//*[@class='primary btn btn-primary']"
remDrv$findElement(using="xpath",select_path)$clickElement()
```

Probably late but I hope it helps someone. The key was to cleverly construct xpaths.